# Json parsing in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <script>
        alert("ciao");
        $.getJSON('', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 

        });
    </script>

    <body >
        <p>ciao<p>
    </body>

</html>
```

With this code I want to parse this JSON:

asd'cp'pd'pcd'sp'sdp'dc

The browser console give me this error (I don't understand what it means):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php?get_param=value. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Read about [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: In with way i can solve the problem? Can you help me?

Comment: Plus json/javascript hash keys may not contain spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I think your are trying to do a cross domain ajax request.Browser will block the request because of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

If you need to access the data from another domain i'll suggest you to  use `jsonp`. But for that, the required server should bind the return data with a client side function.

Refer [this](http://json-p.org/).

Also you can try enabling `cors` in the ajax request.

Comment: Can you make me an example?

Comment: @user3485122 please check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/239/. Its an example for cors enabled server..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crossDomain: true` in jQuery ajax.
Check this [**link**](http://sreesexperiencetoshare.blogspot.com/2013/01/resolving-same-origin-policy.html) for details